# can I use "own" in progressive?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-tense, present-perfect-progressive

**I ...... this car for more than ten years.**

a) have owned
b) have been owning
c) owned
d) will own
So what's the difference between a,b and c

Comment: (a) you still own it, (b) nobody would say this, (c) you don't own it any more, (d) you don't own it yet.

Comment: Some verbs are hardly ever used in the continuous (progressive) tense. We can say _people have been owning cars for many years_ (many people have possessed cars at different times), but not _I have been owning a car_.